# Is this code a resource release issue? Fortify is flagging this as a failure to release data base resource (connection)

Tags: using, idisposable, fortify

```
using (var cnn = getConnection()) { 

    try {
        cnn.Open()
        ....
    }

    catch(exception e) {
       log(e.message);
       throw(e);  
    }

 }
```

Fortify is claiming the above code will not release the connection due to the re-throwing of the exception.  Everything I read about using blocks indicates this code will hit the idisposable call generated by the using block.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if you move the using block, inside the try catch, then Fortify will not consider this a resource release database issue.